# MSVS 2008 : Form throws ArgumentException was unhandled by user code Error when modified

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 
using
Microsoft net framework Version 3.5 SP1

I am attempting to modify a working form.  Upon initially adding buttons / fields and then subsequently running the program, the form threw an exception.

Exception :

```
"ArgumentException was unhandled by user code"
"Cannot add primary key constraint since primary key is already set for the table"
```

From what I have found it has to do with trying to modify or enforce constraints on an inherited data-table/database.  Is there any auto generated which could be causing this error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: can you show the call stack + offending code

Comment: I am not able to show it entirely,

Comment: at System.Data.ConstraintCollection.FinishInitConstraints() 
 at System.Data.DataTable.EndInit() 
 Initialization of components method called. @jeroenh

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx

Comment: We are not able to answer it entirely.

Comment: [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821536)  This is effectively the problem I am having with reproduction of the code. @jeroenh @Hans Passant

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in my initial question I was searching for the function that I could delete to keep this from happening.  And even though @jeroenh thought so valiantly that I did not give enough information to answer this question, I'd like to point out the function is

.Constraints.AddRange()

^ you'll note it had to do with constraints from a data-table.